# Writing a key on top level with QSettings

Tags: qt, ini, qsettings

I'm using QSettings to parse a ini-format file without a group, like this one:

```
msg=45
id=69
```

So far so good, but when I try to write a new key, it goes like this:

```
[General]
new=100
msg=45
id=69
```

My goal is to have something like this:

```
msg=45
id=69
new=100
```

This is my code fro writing:

```
QSettings settings(m_rcFile, QSettings::IniFormat);
settings.setValue("new", num);
```

I know most ini files have group/key/value but since QSetings can read them without a group I though that it can do the same for writing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems consistent with the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#Format-enum) at least, which says

> if you save a top-level setting (a key with no slashes in it, e.g., "someKey"), it will appear in the INI file's "General" section.

Just below it says

> Following the philosophy that we should be liberal in what we accept and conservative in what we generate, QSettings will [...]

which, while addressing a different quirk, could explain why QSettings can read values from a non-section, but refuses to write there.

Bottom line is that you need a different approach (another library or a low-level class like QFile/QTextStream) to write those values if you really cannot put them in a section.

Comment: The thing is that the ini file can have user-defined values.